# Magento Recurring Profile Coupon Issue

Tags: magento

I have a recurring profile (nominal item) setup and its working fine, however when I try and apply a coupon code at the checkout, it seems to add a figure to the grand total (which should be 0) and then wont let me checkout. At no point does it let me take money off the total of the recurring profile price, I'm on magento 1.9 theres no errors in the error log.

Edit: on another look its taken a random amount off the recurring profile amount and added it to the grand total amount.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System>Configuration>Sales>Tax>Calculation Settings`
and select "`Apply Customer Tax`" to "`Before Discount`" and "`Apply Discount on Prices`" to "`Including Tax`".
Save Config.
This will work.